# ASP .NET MVC 4 WebApi: Manually handle OData queries

Tags: rest, odata, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web Service made using the **WebAPI** provided by ASP .NET MVC 4.
I know that the layer on top of which WebAPI works automatically handles **OData Queries** (such as `$filter`, `$top`, `$skip`), but what if I want to handle the filtering by myself?

[I don't simply return data from my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgv8W.jpg), but I have another layer which adds some properties, makes some conversions etc. So querying ALL of my data, converting them and returning them to the WebAPI class for OData filtering isn't just good enough. It's of course terribly slow, and generally a crappy idea.

So is there a way to **propagate the OData query parameters** from my WebAPI entry point to the functions I call to get and convert the data?

For example, a GET to `/api/people?$skip=10&$top=10` would call on the server:

```
public IQueryable<Person> get() {
    return PersonService.get(SomethingAboutCurrentRequest.CurrentOData);
}
```

And in `PersonService`:

```
public IQueryable<Person> getPeople(var ODataQueries) {
    IQueryable<ServerSidePerson> serverPeople = from p in dbContext.ServerSidePerson select p;
    // Make the OData queries
    // Skip
    serverPeople = serverPeople.Skip(ODataQueries.Skip);
    // Take
    serverPeople = serverPeople.Take(ODataQueries.Take);
    // And so on
    // ...

    // Then, convert them
    IQueryable<Person> people = Converter.convertPersonList(serverPeople);
    return people;
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I just stumbled across this old post and I'm adding this answer as it's now very easy to handle the OData queries yourself. Here's an example:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Example")]
public IEnumerable<Poco> GetExample(ODataQueryOptions<Poco> queryOptions)
{
    var data = new Poco[] { 
        new Poco() { id = 1, name = "one", type = "a" },
        new Poco() { id = 2, name = "two", type = "b" },
        new Poco() { id = 3, name = "three", type = "c" }
    };

    var t = new ODataValidationSettings() { MaxTop = 2 };
    queryOptions.Validate(t);

    //this is the method to filter using the OData framework
    //var s = new ODataQuerySettings() { PageSize = 1 };
    //var results = queryOptions.ApplyTo(data.AsQueryable(), s) as IEnumerable<Poco>;

    //or DIY
    var results = data;
    if (queryOptions.Skip != null) 
        results = results.Skip(queryOptions.Skip.Value);
    if (queryOptions.Top != null)
        results = results.Take(queryOptions.Top.Value);

    return results;
}

public class Poco
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is the most complete/correct answer, thank you very much, I will use this in my next projects.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/Roysvork/LinqToQuerystring/, this gives you the option to create an IQueryable<> directly from a raw odata query string.

Comment: A bit detailed explanation of manual OData query handling: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/02/25/translating-odata-queries-to-hql.aspx and corresponding example: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/72014f4c779e#Samples/WebApi/NHibernateQueryableSample/Readme.txt

Comment: @qujck Are you achieving this in an ApiController or a normal MVC controller?

Comment: @qujck Furthermore could you add your WebApiConfig / RouteConfig configuration to this answer?

Comment: It was over 4 years ago that I posted this answer, and the code is long gone now.

Comment: @qujck I figured it out, `configuration.EnableDependencyInjection();` should be enabled in the `WebApiConfig`

Answer (score 4):

The query from the URL gets translated into a LINQ expression tree which is then executed against the IQueryable your operation returns. You can analyze the expression and provide the results in any way you want. The downside is that you need to implement IQueryable which is not super easy. Take a look at this blog post series if you're interested: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vitek/archive/2010/02/25/data-services-expressions-part-1-intro.aspx. It talks about WCF Data Services, but the filter expressions used by the Web API will be very similar.

Answer (score 2):

One way With Web-api would be with customer message handler http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers

**Write a custom handler like below:**

```
public class CustomHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(
                (task) =>
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = task.Result;
                    var persons = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IQueryable<Person>>().Result;
                    var persons2 = new List<Person>(); //This can be the modified model completely different
                    foreach (var item in persons)
                    {
                        item.Name = "changed"; // here you can change the data
                        //persons2.Add(....); //Depending on the results modify this custom model
                    }
                    //overwrite the response
                    response = new HttpResponseMessage<IEnumerable<Person>>(persons2); 
                    return response;
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

**Register in global.asax.cs**

Method in application class:

```
static void Configure(HttpConfiguration config)
 {
     config.MessageHandlers.Add(new CustomHandler()); 
 }

protected void Application_Start()
{
     ....
     .....
     //call the configure method
     Configure(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
 }
```

Comment: I am afraid this is not doable, as the database-classes and return-classes are completely different and it is not possible (for some reasons) to do the conversions in a custom handler.

Comment: Then change the response. Edited above. `var persons2 = new List<Person>(); //This can be the modified model completely different   `  `response = new HttpResponseMessage<IEnumerable<Person>>(persons2);`

Comment: The biggest problem here is that you aren't properly consuming IQueryable by filtering it.  Instead you are enumerating the full results and building up a new result set manually.  This defeats using any underlying linq providers.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this with WCF Data Services and asp.net mvc 3.5 but it was a bit of a kludge.

The first step is to rewrite the path so that the skip and top options don't get applied twice, once by you and once by the runtime.

I did the rewriting with an HttpModule.  In your BeginRequest method you'd have code like this:

```
HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.Contains(YOUR_SVC))
{
    if (app.Request.Url.Query.Length > 0)
    {
        //skip questionmark
        string queryString = app.Request.Url.Query.Substring(1) 
                    .Replace("$filter=", "filter=")
                    .Replace("$orderby=", "orderby=")
                    .Replace("$top=", "top=")
                    .Replace("$skip=", "skip=");

                HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(app.Request.Path, "", queryString);
    }
}
```

Then just examine the query string and pluck out the parameters you need.

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["filter"] != null)
    var filter = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["filter"] as string;
```

Then split the filter string and parse it into a sql statement or any other db commands.  I was using NHibernate in my case.  I was also able to limit what filter commands I supported  which made things easier. I didn't do groupings for example.  Mostly just the comparison operators.

There's a list of filter operators at [OData.org](http://www.odata.org/documentation/uri-conventions#FilterSystemQueryOption).  Split the string by "and" and "or" into individual clauses.  Split each clause by a space and you should get a 3 element array with the property name in [0] the operator in [1] and the value in [2].

The clauses will be in terms of a Person but I'm assuming you'll be able to convert them into something that will pull the right results out of the db.

I ended up abandoning this approach since it won't work for POSTS.  I had to write my own Linq provider but writing my own filter string parser made that easier to understand.

Comment: This might just be what I was looking for. Thank you!!! Is there a way to automatically apply the filters to the IQueryable or will I have to do everything manually?

Comment: Manually unfortunately.  This method basically just turns the filter into arrays of strings.  In NH this wasn't so bad since it's easy to build queries dynamically.

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(app.Request.Path, "", queryString);` doesn't seem to be working. The path gets changed but the layer on top of `ApiController` looks like it's still processing the old `$skip` and `$top`. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Sorry I don't.  This could be one of the differences between WebAPI and WCF data services.  You could try switching to data services.  The only hard part was the custom linq provider which I don't think you'll need.  The other (kludgy) approach I took to get around the skip and top problem was to insert a bunch of dummy items into the list I created.  Then when it skips it'll start at your real data.  That won't handle expands though (at least not without a lot of work).