# Get request to api with predicate expression as a parameter

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, api

Is it possible to use a predicate expression as a parameter for an HTTPGET request (to a mvc api controller).

Background: I`m trying to build a car rental web application.
using MSsql for db, EntityFramework (code-first), a repository for (generic) CRUD functions and MVC API controller.

My aim is to send queries to db through api controller using predicate linq expression.
the code:

repository:

```
public IQueryable<T> Search<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class, IDataEntity
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
    }
```

api get(**predicate Expression parameter**) function:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(Expression<Func<Car, bool>> predicate)
    {
        using (IRepository Manager = Factories.Factory.GetRepository())
        {
            var CarList = Manager.Search<Car>(predicate)
                .Select(x => new CarDTO()
                {
                    ...
                })
                .ToList();
            return Request.CreateResponse<List<CarDTO>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, CarList);
        }
    }
```

client html angular/jq ajax request:

```
$http.get("/api/CarApi"+"??????",{params:{ ??????? }})
            .success(function (result) {
                $scope.filteredCarsList = result;
                ...
            })
            .error(function (result) {
                ...
            });
```

(Im using agulars $http for ajax request, similar to $.getJSON)

Is it possible to send a predicate expression through a ajax (get) request to an api controller who expect to get a linq expression as a parameter?

if so, how?
and if not, what is the correct/appropriate way to achieve my goal?

Comment: possibly this helps: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP .NET MVC 4 WebApi: Manually handle OData queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781309/asp-net-mvc-4-webapi-manually-handle-odata-queries)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is useful to you, but you can use the [Dynamic Linq Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/). This way you can easily construct queries at runtime and query using strings.

More information found [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library).